# How to find the longest sequence of "broken" characters using Regex in JS?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find the longest sequence of "broken"(different from letter, digit, space) characters in this sentence:

**'Tempera####&&#^ na @#$ata 23 grad#%&.'**

I really want to do it using Regex, but I'm not that familiar with the usage of Regex in JS. This is the description of the problem: https://pastebin.com/U6Uukc4b
I watched a lot of tutorials, also read bunch of articles and this is what I came up with:

```js
let input = [
        'Tempera####&&#^ na @#$ata 23 grad#%&.'
];

let print = this.print || console.log;
let gets = this.gets || ((arr, index) => () => arr[index++])(input, 0);

let message = gets();

//different from letter, digit, space

let counter = 1;
let allWords = /[a-z1-9\s]/gi;

for (let i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
  let current = message[i];
  // allWords.lastIndex = 0;
  let isExisting = allWords.test(current);

  if (current === '.') {
    break;
  }
  if (isExisting) {
    counter = 1;

  } else {
    counter++;
  }


}

print(counter)
```

Here the answer should be 8 , because we have 8 consecutive symbols inside the word `"Tempera####&&#^"` , which are not letter, digit or space.

Unfortunately this doesn't work. I'm still trying to understand where is my mistake, so I'll be very thankful if someone can "show me the way".

Comment: I made a snippet of the code posted but notice this has a syntax error `let input = [
        ''Tempera####&&#^ na @#$ata 23 grad#%&.''
];`

Comment: Oh, yes, I will edit it. It's not like that in my code, so the issue is somewhere else .. : / But thanks!

Comment: Your question explains what broken characters are, which would include a point, but then your code deals with a point separately. This contradicts the explanation.

Comment: I would recommend you put this in a function and then decide what to do with it rather than the `print(counter)` since that is outside the question scope and does odd things in a  question here.  Recommend you just use a `console.log(somevariable)` here for simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const input = 'Tempera####&&#^ na @#$ata 23 grad#%&.';
function findLongestSubstring(input) {
  let longest = '';
  let current = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].match(/[^a-zA-Z\d\s]/)) {
      current += input[i];
    } else {
      if (current.length > longest.length) {
        longest = current;
      }
      current = '';
    }
  }
  return longest.length;
}
console.log(findLongestSubstring(input));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression that matches the opposite (`[^.....]`) and as many times as possible (`+`). Then check the size of all matches and pick the longest length. As there is a special role for the point (which apparently is always at the end), consider it as not broken.

```js
let allWords = /[^a-z1-9\s.]+/gi;

let input = [
    'Tempera####&&#^ na @#$ata 23 grad#%&.'
];
for (let message of input) {
    let results = message.match(allWords) ?? [];
    let counter = Math.max(0, ...results.map(({length}) => length));
    console.log("longest", counter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! Sorry, but I'm not that experienced, so what you wrote looks very beautiful, but it's not easy to understand for me and also didn't work in my code. I don't understand the last part in the result variable - ?? [] . I also don't get what are we doing with map ({length}) => length). ( I know what does map do , but in this particular case wasn't clear for me)

Comment: If it didn't work in your code, can you edit your question and provide the surrounding code and/or data, so I can take into account?

Comment: `?? []` is necessary in case there is no match at all. In that case  `.match()` returns `null`, which I don't want. In that case `?? []` will replace that `null` with an empty array.

Comment: `.map(({length}) => length)` has the same effect as `.map(str => str.length)`. It is just a different syntax, using destructuring, so that I immediately have access to `length` without needing a `str` variable.

Comment: I posted the entire code. It's a problem I'm trying to solve and here is the description: https://pastebin.com/U6Uukc4b ( because it's too long). I spent many hours researching Regex, so I thought that I'm not using Regex methods correctly. But thanks a lot for your explanation, this is something I'll try to remember.

Comment: You should edit your question and add this information there. Make sure to explain the role of the point, because that you didn't mention in your description. I added the point in the regular expression, as it needs to be treated as non-broken. If it doesn't work, then please provide the input for which it doesn't work.